# Get price free without KYC via API?

Tags: python, price, kyc

How could I get ethereum price free without KYC via API?
It would be great if I could get it in every second

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

Call the etherscan.io community price API.

`https://api.etherscan.io/api?module=stats&action=ethprice`

You can make up to 5 calls a second without an API key.

It will return:

```
{
    "status": "1",
    "message": "OK-Missing/Invalid API Key, rate limit of 1/5sec applied",
    "result": {
        "ethbtc": "0.08209",
        "ethbtc_timestamp": "1640101932",
        "ethusd": "3977.09",
        "ethusd_timestamp": "1640101937",
    },
}
```

Example code in Python

```py
import requests

etherscan_api = 'https://api.etherscan.io/api?module=stats&action=ethprice'
price = requests.get(etherscan_api).json()['result']

eth_btc = price['ethbtc']
eth_usd = price['ethusd']

print(eth_btc)
>>> 0.08209
print(eth_usd)
>>> 3977.09
```